# .NET EF MVC not loading property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been trying to get something done in .NET EF for some time now.

My model looks like this:

```
public class Route
    {
        [Key]
    public int RouteId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Rope")]
    public int ropeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Rope rope { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Routesetter")]
    public int routeSetterId { get; set; }
    public virtual RouteSetter routeSetter { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Secundary routesetter")]
    public int? secundaryRouteSetterId { get; set; }
    public virtual RouteSetter secundaryRouteSetter { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Grade")]
    public int gradeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ClimbingGrade grade { get; set; }
    [Display (Name = "Routename")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Color")]
    public int colorId { get; set; }
    public virtual GripColor color { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display (Name ="Date set")]
    public DateTime dateSet { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display (Name ="Date removed")]
    public DateTime? dateRemoved { get; set; }
    [Display (Name ="Marked for removal")]
    public bool markedForRemoval { get; set; }

}
```

The controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var routes = db.Routes.Include(r => r.color).Include(r => r.grade).Include(r => r.rope).Include(r => r.routeSetter).Include(r => r.secundaryRouteSetter);
        ViewBag.Page = "Routes";
        return View(routes.ToList());
    }
```

Now the color property is always null. while all other properties are loaded.

I can't seem to figure this one out. Any help would be welcome

**EDIT**
The GripColor clas:

```
 public class GripColor
{
    [Key]
    public int GripColorId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Primary color")]
    public string primaryColor { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Secundary color")]
    public string secundaryColor { get; set; }

    public string displayName { get { return primaryColor + ' ' + secundaryColor; } }
    public virtual List<Route> Routes { get; set; }
}
```

I assume the gripColors are OK in the database;

```
ViewBag.ColorID = new SelectList(db.Colors, "GripColorId", "displayName");
```

The above is used to populate a dropdown (wich works) And the colorId is stored correctly in the database

Comment: Are sure that data exists in these tables? If there is issue in the query, it will just throw exception. But if it returns no result, then something is with data or with INNER JOINs to that data

Comment: Another thing you can do, if you're using SQL Server, is run the SQL profiler to see what commands are actually going to the database. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJ8Dyv4Uk6E https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx Stick a debug point on the return statement and look at the list.

Comment: Also check what var colors = db.GripColors.ToList(); returns...

Comment: What does `GripColor` class  look like? I assume you need to initialize color in `GripColor` class

Comment: It sounds like you haven't configured your model so that EF knows that `colorId` is a foreign key to the `GripColor` table.

Comment: Thanks @DStanley That did indeed seem to be the problem

Answer (score 1):

There is no **foreign key** relating the two tables, then how are you expecting to make inner joins between them?You should setup the relationship between these two tables and define the foreign key.You can use data annotations for this purpose or i highly recommend using fluent api.Check out this documentation for more info:

http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/index.html